# DataTables child row or nested table on init

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm wondering if there is a way to make chosen columns appear in nested/child row like in [this example from DataTables.net](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) but without this manual parsing with jquery?

There are similar questions but none was answered, so I'm hoping this question will get more attention :)

I've tried `responsive` option like this:

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "scrollY":'60vh',
        "scrollCollapse":true,
        //"scrollX":true,
        "responsive":true,
        "ajax": {
            "url":upTableUrl,
            "data":function(d) {
              d.file = $.urlParam('file');//'data_extr.json';
            search_obj = d;
           }
      },      "columns":[
              ...
      ],
      "columnDefs":[
              ...
      ]
    });
```

and some html (Watch out for django here):

```
<table width="100%" class="display nowrap table table-striped table-bordered" id="example" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              {% for col in columns %}<th>{{col}}</th>
              {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            {% for col in columns %}<th>{{col}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
```

The table is still x-axis-scrollable and no buttons or other stuff appearing.

Comment: please show the code you've tried

Comment: Sorry, but the code won't be much helpful, since I have no idea how to do it except for how it was solved in DataTables examples, which is what I want to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Row details](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) requires from you to write your own formatting function.

However you can use [Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension where columns can be displayed in a child row under certain conditions.

By default extension hides all columns that don't fit the container in a child row, see [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/option.html).

However you can control visibility of the columns with [special classes](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes)  applied either to corresponding `th` element or using [`columns.className`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) option, see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/2cjrum77/).

Comment: Example is tad enigmatic, but it seems like a good direction. Although it states that 'The Responsive extension for DataTables can be applied [...] with a specific class name on the table, or using the DataTables initialisation options', which means that I can choose which columns will appear in details section by applying some class? Is it certain class or I have to point that during initialization? The 'responsive' option documentation does not say much :(

Comment: Is there some sort of collision with ajax-loaded data? Because example says that 'set this value `responsive` to `true` and import datatables.responsive.min.js and watch the magick happen'
So I'm looking and nothing...

Comment: @PiotrKamoda, by default only columns that don't fit the screen are hidden in a child row. You need to use classes on `th` elements to hide certain columns regardless of screen width, see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/2cjrum77/).